# Accessing and inserting to a map of maps (nested map) in C++

Tags: c++

I wish to work with a map of maps data structure that looks something like:

`map <int, map <Student, int>>` . The key of the outer map corresponds to id, the key of the inner map corresponds to student information (where Student is a class) and the value of inner map corresponds to the grade of the student.

I am facing difficulties in the following:

1. Inserting new values to this data structure
2. Accessing grade (value of the inner map) and member variables within the Student class (key of the inner map)
3. Iterating over the map to print Student and grade information.

Thanks!

Comment: Please give it a try. If you get stuck, ask questions that are specific to where you are stuck, preferably with a [mcve].

Comment: I'm not sure how this data structure is supposed to work.  Is the ID the student ID?  If so, then why do you need the map as the value?  Wouldn't there only be one Student in the map?  If not, what does the ID refer to?

Regardless, I would start by just working on getting the inner map working and then work on including it in the outer map next so that you aren't trying to fight too many moving parts at once.

Answer (score 1):

No need for nested maps:

- `Student` class should have a public member (or function) for the student ID.
- You can then create a `map<ID, student_grade>` to search the grade based on student ID.

Another approach is to store the grade in the Student class:

```
map<int, Student> students;
// ...
int grade = student[ID].grade;
string name = student[ID].name;
```

Comment: How would I retrieve student name given the id?
Although this method could potentially serve my purpose, I would like to understand the usage of nested maps in general. Could you please provide insight on that as well?